# jQuery for getting Click event on a Table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table

```
<table>
<tr class="rows"><td>cell1</td><td>cell2</td></tr>
</table>
```

How can i set an alert message if i clicked on `any of the column of <tr class="rows">` using jquery?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use delegate for better performance which will attach click event to root container of rows i.e table

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tableSelector").delegate("tr.rows", "click", function(){
        alert("Click!");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, How can I get the colomn hearder html inside this function?

Comment: @NikhilDinesh - You can use the `event.target` to find out which column is clicked and get the index of it. Using the index you can select the required column from the header and get the html.

Comment: How can I get the td content ("cell1" and "cell2" text from the question example)?

Comment: `delegate` is deprecated now. Use `.on` instead

Answer (score 13):

```
$(
  function(){
      $(".rows").click(
        function(e){
            alert("Clicked on row");
            alert(e.target.innerHTML);
        }
      )
  }
)
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/oyunel/edit)

Better solution

```
$(document).on("click","tr.rows td", function(e){
    alert(e.target.innerHTML);
});
```

Comment: $(document).on("click","tr.rows td", function(e){
    alert(e.target.innerHTML);
});
This worked great for new row added

Answer (score 5):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr.rows").click(function(){
        alert("Click!");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".rows").click(function (){ 
   alert('click');
});
```